# php regex/preg_match for beginner

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am not good at expressions
I would like to match the string below of a string.

```
http://www.site.com/ * .js

preg_match('(http://www\.site\.com/).*(\.js)',$html,$match);
```

I know this code is not right. * Represents any file with .js extension.
Could anyone guide me with the expression.
Sorry if any duplication.

Comment: preg_match("/www.site.com.+.js/",$html,$match);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use delimiters such as '#', '@' or '/' in the pattern :

```
$url = 'http://www.site.com/javascript/test.js';

$preg_match = preg_match('#(http://www\.site\.com/)(.*)(\.js)#', $url, $matches);

if($preg_match === 1)
{
    var_dump($matches);
    // displays :
    // array
    //   0 => string 'http://www.site.com/javascript/test.js' (length=38)
    //   1 => string 'http://www.site.com/' (length=20)
    //   2 => string 'javascript/test' (length=15)
    //   3 => string '.js' (length=3)
}
else
{
    // doesn't match
}
```